# Multilevel 'do' in Perl?

Tags: perl, perl-module

This question may look simple, but I am thinking on this over past some days, I couldn't find the answer.

I have multilevel scripting architecture (the code is shown below)

**CallingScript.pl (Include toplevel library and check for compiler-error)**

```
do "IncludesConsumer.pm";

print "\n callingScript error : $@" if($@ || $!);

do "IncludesConsumer.pm";

print "\n callingScript error : $@" if($@);

do "IncludesConsumer.pm";

print "\n callingScript error : $@" if($@);
```

**IncludesConsumer.pm (adds the library INCLUDES.pm and has its own functions)**

```
do "INCLUDES.pm";

print "\nin IncludesConsumer";
```

**INCLUDES.pm ( multiple modules in one place, acts as a library )**

```
use Module;

print "\n in includes";
```

**Module.pm (with syntax-error)**

```
use strict;

sub MakeSyntaxError
{
    print "\nerror in Module 
}

1;
```

In concept, once of the core Modules(e.g. Module.pm) may contain syntax errors. So I need to capture them in CallingScript.pl. i.e: I would like to capture the syntax error in `Module.pm` (low-level) in the `CallingScript.pl` file.

**OUTPUT:**

```
D:\Do_analysis>CallingScript.pl

in IncludesConsumer
in IncludesConsumer
in IncludesConsumer
```

Why is the compiler-erro not caught in CallingScript.pl?
Please pour-in your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: @simbabque: Maybe. Then tell me how to `do` it right? :)

Comment: Why are you `do`ing the modules in the first place? They should have `package`s in them. And functions. But not a lot of code that is being run right when they are included by `do` or `require`. It's a bit odd. Put the code that you want to run multiple times in a function, put that in your `.pm`, wrap it in a `package` and `require` that.

Answer (score 5):

Five errors, starting with the one causing the problem you are asking about:

- You didn't handle errors from some of the `do`.
- You only check `$!` some of the time.
- `$!` can be true even if there was error. Only check `$!` is both `do` and `$@` are false.
- All but one of the your included file didn't signal a lack of error (`1;`). You need to return true so `do` returns true, so you know whether an error occurred or not.
- You `use`d a file that doesn't have a `package`.
- `CallingScript.pl`:

  ```
  do "IncludesConsumer.pm" or die "CallingScript: ".($@ || $!);
  do "IncludesConsumer.pm" or die "CallingScript: ".($@ || $!);
  do "IncludesConsumer.pm" or die "CallingScript: ".($@ || $!);
  ```
- `IncludesConsumer.pm` (which isn't actually a "pm"):

  ```
  do "INCLUDES.pm" or die "IncludesConsumer: ".($@ || $!);
  print "\nin IncludesConsumer";
  1;
  ```
- `INCLUDES.pm` (which isn't actually a "pm"):

  ```
  use Module;
  print "\n in includes";
  1;
  ```
- `Module.pm` (with syntax-error)

  ```
  package Module;
  sub MakeSyntaxError {
  1;
  ```

There's really no reason to use `do` in this fashion. It's a very poor programming practice. please avoid it in favor of modules.

Comment: Terrific! Thanks for explaining the stuffs part-by-part. this was what missing=> `do "INCLUDES.pm" or die "IncludesConsumer: $@";`

Comment: Not so, you were also missing two `1;` and one `package Module;`, and you had a number of incorrect `if $@` and `if $!`. And that's not even counting the fact that you have four uses of `do` too many.

Comment: Valid point! But I have two doubts. 1, Is the use `do "IncludesConsumer.pm";

print "\n callingScript error : $@" if($@);` invalid? 2,When we use `do Somemodule.pm`, do we really need `1;`? I know that when we use `use` & `require`, we need `1;`.

Comment: 1) Oops, I guess I misspoke and it isn't. However, you do need to check `$!`, and only if `do` and `$@` are false. (Answer updated) 2) Well, you could rely on `print` succeeding and thus returning true, but that's not a good practice. If you don't return true, you can't always tell if `do` returned an error or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have the following hierarchy:

```
CallingScript
  do IncludesConsumer
    do INCLUDES
      use Module
```

The `use Module` is processed at compile time of `INCLUDES.pm`, which then also fails. After `do "INCLUDES.pm"`, the `$@` variable is set.

However, the `$@` refers to the *last* `eval` (of which `do FILE` is a variant). In `CallingScript.pl`, this is the `do "IncludesConsumer.pm"`, which ran fine.

---

The `do FILE` syntax is unneccessary since the advent of modules to Perl. You want to `use` your files in nearly all cases instead, or `require` them if runtime effects are needed.

If you want to assert that modules can be loaded fine, I refer you to [`Test::More`](https://metacpan.org/module/MSCHWERN/Test-Simple-0.98/lib/Test/More.pm) with the `use_ok` function.

Comment: So one solution is `die $@ if $@;` as appropriate.

Comment: First of all, I am using `do` , to reset the values of global variables in Module.pm. Since the module can be loaded only once using `require`, the global variables in module will retain the previously used values.

Comment: In my usecase, the IncludesConsumer.pm should be loaded as a fresh copy to make sure that there are no previous values present in IncludesConsumer.pm global variables. Hence I am `do`ing INCLUDES.pm also.

Comment: In that case, I'd advice you to also `undef` everything that has previously come from  your IncludesConsumer.pm if it does not have a `package`.

Comment: @InnovWelt A cleaner (but more complex) design would create a module with a function which then modifies the global variables of the calling package. That function can be called any number of times. The [`Package::Stash`](https://metacpan.org/module/DOY/Package-Stash-0.34/lib/Package/Stash.pm) module and the `caller` builtin can help. An even cleaner design would not use global variables, but hashes or objects.

Comment: @simbabque : I might have more global variables. i will be difficult to undef everything without fail. so , i thought , it is better to reload the module using `do`

Comment: From my experience, if the code has multiple conditions in it, sometimes stuff is left over. It can get nasty if that happens.